# SQL: select insert into select + add fixed value fron another table

Tags: sql

Good Mornig,

i have 3 tables:

1° tbl: timestamp_begin, timestamp_end, column1, column2....columnX, id

2° tbl: timestamp, column1, column2 ....columnX

3° tbl: timestamp, column1, column2 ....columnX, id

I need to select all record from tbl 2 WHERE "timestamp" is between "timestamp_begin" and "timestamp_end" off tbl 1 and then insert all record retrieved into a tbl 3 with additional column  (equal for each row) with it value is "id" retrieve from tbl 1.

Is possible do that with a single query command?

Thank a lot for any suggestions

Jumpier

Comment: Forget INTO for now, just write the SELECT query that represents the data you want to insert; use JOIN, use WHERE and anything else to get the exact set of rows and columns you want to insert. Then add INTO (if the table exists its `INSERT INTO x SELECT...`, and if it doesn't exist it's `SELECT ... INTO x FROM ...`

Comment: it may be difficult to understand how the tables relate to each other, can you share some samples from your tables and the expected result given the sample tables?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also, add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming table3 doesn't exist yet:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.[timestamp], t2.column1, t2.column2 INTO table03
FROM table02 t2 INNER JOIN table01 t1 ON t2.[timestamp] BETWEEN t1.timestamp_begin AND t1.timestamp_end
```

If table3 already exists

```
INSERT INTO table03 SELECT t1.id, t2.[timestamp], t2.column1, t2.column2 
FROM table02 t2 INNER JOIN table01 t1 ON t2.[timestamp] BETWEEN t1.timestamp_begin AND t1.timestamp_end
```

As @Caius Jard suggested, you could have begun by creating the select to get the records you wanted to insert, and later modifying it with the select into / insert into syntax.

Comment: Goodmorning

finally i've used this query sintax:
INSERT INTO table03 SELECT t1.id, t2.[timestamp], t2.column1, t2.column2 
FROM table02 t2 INNER JOIN table01 t1 ON t2.[timestamp] BETWEEN t1.timestamp_begin AND t1.timestamp_end WHERE t1.id = 'MyId'